# Why is renv restore() leading to an error on macOS?

Tags: r, xcode, macos, renv

When I enter `renv::restore()` into my RStudio in a project with a renv.lock file, the output in the console is normal but I get a strange error preventing me from installing any of the packages:

```
Error in if (eval(cond, envir = environment(dot))) return(eval(expr, envir = environment(dot))) : 
  the condition has length > 1
In addition: Warning message:
In system2(R(), args, stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE) :
  running command ''/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R' CMD config CC 2>&1' had status 1
```

Not sure if it is something to do with Xcode?

Any help would be super useful.

The error can be repeated by cloning this repository:

```
git clone git@github.com:b-rodrigues/targets-minimal.git
```

And running:

```
renv::restore()
```

I am using R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16) -- "Beagle Scouts".
Renv version 1.0.2
Operating system - macOS Monterey version 12.6.3

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue was I did not have xcode installed.
After re-installing Xcode using the following in the terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Renv now works and I am no longer getting this error!

Shame xcode is such a massive application :'(